# How to fix gcc -Wall "embedded '\0' in format" warning

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, warnings

This may not be very crucial, however I am trying to fix all the warnings g++ is complaining about. In the code below, I am getting "embedded '\0' in format" warning for the snprintf() line.

How can I fix this?

```
    int filePathSize = path.size() + s.size() + 1;
    char filePath[filePathSize];
    snprintf(filePath,filePathSize,"%s%s\0",path.c_str(),s.c_str());
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried removing it (i.e. using "%s%s" instead)?

Comment: Why do you have a null character in your string? Also, your code's not valid C++ because of the variable length array (`filePath[filePathSize]`). It only compiles because g++ implements VLAs in C++ as an extension.

Comment: I am trying to create a file name dynamically, based on the data I read from a specific directory. Shall I include a `null` at the end of the file name, it is fine to leave it without the file name. I use filePath as the first argument to `fopen()` later on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The warning is there for a good reason: `snprintf` is going to think the `\0` marks the end of the string. If you actually need a null to be printed, you can't embed it directly into the string; C strings cannot contain null characters for this very reason. This is the most obvious workaround:

```
snprintf(filePath,filePathSize,"%s%s%c",path.c_str(),s.c_str(),'\0');
```

Comment: I think it should be mentioned, than `snprintf`guarantees to put nul at the end of buffer it writes to. So this puts 2 nuls there. Which is probably not the intention.